# SQL MAX Statement returning wrong column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a DB that looks like

```
Year     Name      TR     AST
1        Player 1  10     3
2        Player 1  23     "-"
3        Player 1  35     5
1        Player 2  32     1
2        Player 2  29     "-"
3        Player 2  50     2
1        Player 3  74     3
2        Player 3  23     1
3        Player 3  93     9
```

I am trying to return the players name and the amount for the MAX TR. So in this case it would be Player 3 with 93 TR.

I am using this SQL query within SQLITE

```
SELECT MAX(TR), name
FROM database
WHERE TR != "-"
```

It returns the correct MAX(TR) but it's giving the wrong Player Name.

```
 93 Player 1
```

I've run other queries like MAX(AST) and it also gives a wrong Player Name. The same Player Name is returned regardless of which MAX query I use which is where the issue is.

I've also tried this trying to follow the order of SQL execution from here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

```
FROM database
WHERE TR != "-"
SELECT MAX(TR), name
```

As well as

```
SELECT name, MAX(TR)
FROM database
GROUP BY name
LIMIT 1
```

And it returns the wrong TR but with the right corresponding name for that TR.

In case it's an issue I had to use

```
WHERE TR != "_"
```

otherwise it would return a player name and the TR "-". I'm not exactly sure why this is either.

Is there any issue with the order of my query statement?

Comment: I'm honestly surprised the query works at all.  Typically if you're using a column and an aggregate function together, you need a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is using `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT name, TR
FROM database
WHERE TR <> '-'
ORDER BY TR DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You don't even need the `max()`.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the previous comment because I see why Max() won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery, probably something like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    TR
FROM
    database
WHERE
    TR IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(TR)
        FROM
            database
        WHERE
            TR != "-"
    )
```

Note that this can give you multiple results when there are multiple players the same TR, which is also the max TR.

Answer (score 0):

The MAX is an aggregate function in SQL. You cannot use in a SELECT statement an aggregate function and a non-aggregate element, such as a column like in your case.

Instead of doing that try this solution:

```
SELECT name, TR 
FROM database
WHERE TR = (
   SELECT MAX(TR)
   FROM database
   WHERE TR != "-"
)
```